# Integrating an equation.

Tags: integration

$$\frac{dN}{dE}= K\left(\frac{E}{E_0}\right)^ {−\left(a + b \ln(E/E_0)\right)} $$

I want to integrate this equation with respect to $E$, with the lower and upper limits as $E_1$ and $E_2$ respectively. $E_0$ is just a number, and so are $a$, $b$ and $K$.
What should be the integration solution?

I tried this by substituting the 'ln(E/Eo)' term as 'x' and then I get something of a Guassian form. But the problem is that, the Guassian that I get has to have limits from 0 to infinity and my integral does not.

Another way I tried is by taking log of the whole term and further substituting 'ln(E/Eo)' as 'x'. But that way does not seem to be correct.

This is a spectral model called 'LogParabola', if it helps.

Comment: Please review [this meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). By adding context to your question you will get better answers and your question won't be closed.

Comment: [wolfram couldn't find anything](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+k*%5Bx%2Fc%5D%5E%5B-%5Ba%2Bb*log%5Bx%2Fc%5D%5D%5D+dx+from+c_1+to+c_2). What leads you to believe there's an easy closed form for this? Especially with this many constants...

Comment: This does not appear to be integrable in terms of known functions (I've tired WolframAlpha and Mathematica for the $\int x^{-(a+b\log x)}~dx$).

Comment: Does the equation belong to a certain model in physics, economics, ... ?

Comment: Yes. It is a spectral model called 'LogParabola' in Astrophysics.